# React-Query knows when data changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am starting to use react-query for querying my backend. Now, every time I update the backend data (using some admin panel), the GUI (react) shows me immediately the new data. How does react frontend know if the backend data has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, found the issue. If I go to admin panel to update data, and go to the react WINDOW again, it auto refetches

Comment: yes, on window activation, it re-fetches.